# Error :No module named qgis

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I am working on Python26,pyqt4 designer and QGIS. My code file (.py file)contains this:

```
   import sys
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
   from qgis.core import *
   from qgis.gui import *
```

but when i try to run it it gives error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\rt_sql_layer_working\DlgQueryBuilder.py", line 29, in <module>
    from qgis import core,gui
ImportError: No module named qgis
```

I already set PATH in environmental variable as

```
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\bin
C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin
```

Comment: Did you set `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: i set just PATH...not pythonpath..wat to set for pythonpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set just `PATH` instead of `PYTHONPATH`, my advice would be to check if the location of the module you want to import is in the `PYTHONPATH` and, if that's not the case, set the `PYTHONPATH` appropriately.

Comment: i set pythonpath to C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python;C:\Python26\DLLs; ....now m getting the error :      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\rt_sql_layer_working\DlgQueryBuilder.py", line 29, in <module>
    from qgis import core,gui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.